# what is this furniture part, where can I find it?

Tags: doors

[image]

Can anyone help me in trying to find this specific piece? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 6):

It is a broom/mop holder.  Comes in many different designs.

They can be found in most stores that sell broom/mops, hardware, big box, dollar stores,